# how to Inactive multiple users in openAM

Tags: rest, openam, opendj, forgerock

How can I inactive my OpenAM user in a one Go.

I have more than 500 users, and I'd like to inactive my 250 users at one go. How to?

Rest API will also work for multiple users.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually OpenAM is only consuming identity information from the configured user data stores / identity stores, so I would suggest to perform the deativation there. If you are using an LDAP Directory Server, you could just run ldapmodify with an LDFI file that updates the value of attribute configured as 'account status attribute' (default 'inetUserStatus') to 'inactive'.